# Transform viewpager to fullscreen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fullscreen

How can I make a viewpager with next and previous pages, and then when scrolling in the content the current page is transformed with animation to fullscreen and then when the scroll is at zero again transform the view as it was at the beginning.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4MsN.png)

how can I transform a page to fullscreen?

Comment: I did not understand your problem, can you provide more info on it?

Comment: I need to transform my current page to fullscreen... currently I have a carousel with previous and next page. I would like to apply a transformation on the page when scrolling over the content of the current page.